# MVC4 Visual basic routes and parameters

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, parameters, routes

I  know similar question has been already asked but that is not solution for my problem. I have a problem with routes and parameters in my MVC4 VB app. Problem is when I go to /product it asks for parameter and that is OK.

But /product?id=0 is working and /product/1 is not working.

IIS throws ex "The resource cannot be found" on last example

I had same problem with previous project and I did something but I cant remember what I did. 
I know that route should work fine but...

Route:

```
 routes.MapRoute("product", "product/{id}/{name}", New With {.controller = "product", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional, .name= UrlParameter.Optional})
```

Controller:

```
 Function Index(ByVal id As Integer, Optional name As String = "") As ActionResult
        Return View("Product")
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, In Application_Start() method I had

```
 RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
```

and changed it to

```
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)`
```

Now it works, it seams that MVC automatically created routes based on view folders and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is caused by having multiple optional parameters. Since they're both optional the routing engine wouldnt know whether the 1 was the id or the name

To fix it you'll have to define separate routes such as

routes.MapRoute("product-id", "product/{id}", New With {.controller = "product", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional})

routes.MapRoute("product-id-and-name", "product/{id}/{name}", New With {.controller = "product", .action = "Index"})

For a more detailed explanation see

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx/

Comment: That was not the problem, I have found it. MVC automatically  assigned routes by view folders and ignored my custom routes.